# Play Framework 2.6 action builder with Json BodyParser?

Tags: scala, playframework

I've defined custom action with custom request like this:

```
class UserRequest[A](val user: Option[UserFront], request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

case class UserAction (parser: BodyParser[AnyContent])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends ActionBuilder[UserRequest, AnyContent] with ActionTransformer[Request, UserRequest] {
 Here is implementation, cutted
}
```

Now I can use this action in controller like this:

```
UserAction(parse.defaultBodyParser){ implicit request: UserRequest[_] =>

}
```

The problem is: I can't use it with Json body parser

if I change code to

```
UserAction(parse.json){ implicit request: UserRequest[_] =>

}
```

I got compile error:

> type mismatch;   found   :
>   play.api.mvc.BodyParser[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]   required:
>   play.api.mvc.BodyParser[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `AnyContent` is not `JsValue`

Comment: @cchantep I know, but what should I put there to be able to use my Action with any content?

Comment: Any content is not `AnyContent`, would suggest to look at generic and replace `AnyContent` by a type parameter

Comment: Thanks, can you make your comment an answer?